Exception: Cannot load model parameters from checkpoint /home/krish/content/1.2B_last_checkpoint.pt; please ensure that the architectures match
I am fine-tuning the M2M model, with 1.2B model as the last checkpoint. But while training the model I am getting this error that it cannot load the paramters and the model architechure should match
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/krish/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 75, in _wrap
fn(i, *args)
File "/home/krish/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fairseq/distributed/utils.py", line 328, in distributed_main
main(cfg, **kwargs)
File "/home/krish/content/train.py", line 165, in main
extra_state, epoch_itr = checkpoint_utils.load_checkpoint(
File "/home/krish/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fairseq/checkpoint_utils.py", line 248, in load_checkpoint
extra_state = trainer.load_checkpoint(
File "/home/krish/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fairseq/trainer.py", line 580, in load_checkpoint
raise Exception(
Exception: Cannot load model parameters from checkpoint /home/krish/content/1.2B_last_checkpoint.pt; please ensure that the architectures match.
The code that I executed:
try:
train_command = 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" python /home/krish/content/train.py /home/krish/content/Hindi_Marathi/wmt22_spm/wmt22_bin \
        --arch transformer_wmt_en_de_big \
        --task translation_multi_simple_epoch \
        --finetune-from-model /home/krish/content/1.2B_last_checkpoint.pt \
        --save-dir /home/krish/content/Hindi_Marathi/checkpoint \
        --langs \'hi,mr\' \
        --lang-pairs \'hi-mr\' \
        --max-tokens 1200 \
        --encoder-normalize-before --decoder-normalize-before \
        --sampling-method temperature --sampling-temperature 1.5 \
        --encoder-langtok src --decoder-langtok \
        --criterion label_smoothed_cross_entropy --label-smoothing 0.2 \
        --optimizer adam --adam-eps 1e-06 --adam-betas \'(0.9, 0.98)\' \
        --lr-scheduler inverse_sqrt --lr 3e-05 \
        --warmup-updates 2500 --max-update 40000 \
        --dropout 0.3 --attention-dropout 0.1 \
        --weight-decay 0.0 \
        --update-freq 2 --save-interval 5 \
        --save-interval-updates 5000 --keep-interval-updates 3 \
        --no-epoch-checkpoints \
        --seed 222 \
        --log-format simple \
        --log-interval 2 \
        --encoder-layers 12 --decoder-layers 12 \
        --encoder-layerdrop 0.05 --decoder-layerdrop 0.05 \
        --share-decoder-input-output-embed \
        --share-all-embeddings \
        --ddp-backend no_c10d'


This was the training script. Here, I have checked with the model that the arch is "transformer_wmt_en_de_big" only. How should I proceed to resolve this?

Hi, welcome to SO! Could you include the exact exception? Does the file mentioned in the error exist?

Yes, the file mentioned in the error exists. This is the exact exception that I am getting

import torch

checkpoint = torch.load('/home/prajna/krish/content/1.2B_last_checkpoint.pt')
print(checkpoint['args'].arch)

This will give you the architecture used for training the checkpoint.

I have already tried that, and the arch provided is what I have included in my script: transformer_wmt_en_de_big
